# how to increase performance of new created nextjs app in lighthouse

Tags: reactjs, next.js, lighthouse, next.js13

I have created a fresh nextjs app and open it browser in lighthouse, but its performance is too much low. How to improve this following error.

1. Minimize main-thread work -- 9.1 s
2. Reduce JavaScript execution time -- 4.5 s

see screenshot of new nextjs app

[image]

Comment: visit this section of next documents it has good insights on how to improve these metrics
https://nextjs.org/learn/seo/web-performance

Answer (score 2):

Are you running the lighthouse in development mode? Run the in Production mode to verify the actual results.
npm run build && npm run start

Comment: yes i m running it in development mode.

Comment: Run this in production mode. by using this command npm run build && npm run start